# How to create a variable from a condition on other indexed variables in an efficient way?

Tags: r, purrr, dplyr

Let's see an example. For it, I have two observations repeated 4 times:

```
> data(anscombe)
> anscombe
   x1 x2 x3 x4    y1   y2    y3    y4
1  10 10 10  8  8.04 9.14  7.46  6.58
2   8  8  8  8  6.95 8.14  6.77  5.76
3  13 13 13  8  7.58 8.74 12.74  7.71
4   9  9  9  8  8.81 8.77  7.11  8.84
5  11 11 11  8  8.33 9.26  7.81  8.47
6  14 14 14  8  9.96 8.10  8.84  7.04
7   6  6  6  8  7.24 6.13  6.08  5.25
8   4  4  4 19  4.26 3.10  5.39 12.50
9  12 12 12  8 10.84 9.13  8.15  5.56
10  7  7  7  8  4.82 7.26  6.42  7.91
11  5  5  5  8  5.68 4.74  5.73  6.89
```

If I want to see how many of the four times the first observation is greater than 10 and the second is greater than 9, I have at least two options to proceed:

First, reshape the table to long format, sum by group (in this example is like if I have only an id) and reshape again to wide. I can do that, but it does not seem to me very efficient, and if I have too many columns, some indexed and some not, the codes to rehape can be a bit cumbersome.

Second, I can do the next:

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)
anscombe %>%
  mutate(new_var = rowSums(map_dfc(
    1:4,
    ~ anscombe[[paste0("x",.)]] > 10 & anscombe[[paste0("y",.)]] > 9
  ), na.rm = T)) 

   x1 x2 x3 x4    y1   y2    y3    y4 new_var
1  10 10 10  8  8.04 9.14  7.46  6.58       0
2   8  8  8  8  6.95 8.14  6.77  5.76       0
3  13 13 13  8  7.58 8.74 12.74  7.71       1
4   9  9  9  8  8.81 8.77  7.11  8.84       0
5  11 11 11  8  8.33 9.26  7.81  8.47       1
6  14 14 14  8  9.96 8.10  8.84  7.04       1
7   6  6  6  8  7.24 6.13  6.08  5.25       0
8   4  4  4 19  4.26 3.10  5.39 12.50       1
9  12 12 12  8 10.84 9.13  8.15  5.56       2
10  7  7  7  8  4.82 7.26  6.42  7.91       0
11  5  5  5  8  5.68 4.74  5.73  6.89       0
```

Great! It works. But, since in my real data I have much more observations and conditions each time, I would like to do the line `anscombe[[paste0("x",.)]] > 10 & anscombe[[paste0("y",.)]] > 9` shorter.

For example, with `dplyr` functions, data frame name often can be avoided. Maybe I would have to use `rlang` function `sym` as follows:

```
!!sym(paste0("x",.)) > 10 & !!sym(paste0("y",.)) > 9
```

I tried, but it didn't work. Maybe there is some other function than `map_dfc` in `dplyr`, `purrr` or some other package which allow to do this in an easier and more efficient way. Do you have some idea?

Thank you very much.

Comment: Reshaping the data frame from wide to long should be a valid option. Can you be more specific on why it's not your option? And can you show how reshaping doesn't work on your dataset?

Comment: It works, but with my real data I have to specify where too many columns go and I think is not very efficient reshape to have to shape again later.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have been told in github by another option similar to my attempts:

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)
anscombe %>%
  mutate(new_var = rowSums(map_dfc(
    1:4,
    ~ get(paste0("x",.)) > 10 & get(paste0("y",.)) > 9
  ), na.rm = T))
```

which gives me no problem independent on data format (whether it is `Date` or whatever), allows flexibility writing the condition, shorten the script a few and it is intuitive.

Answer (score 4):

**1) split/map2:**  Here is an option with `split` based on the `names` of the dataset.  Here, we remove the digit part at the end from the names, `split` the dataset into a `list` of `data.frames`, using `map2`, pass the vector elements to compare, `reduce` and get the `rowSums`

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)
library(stringr)
anscombe %>%
    split.default(str_remove(names(.), "\\d+$")) %>%
    map2(.,  c(10, 9),  `>`) %>% 
    reduce(`&`) %>% 
    rowSums %>%
    bind_cols(anscombe, new_var = .)
#   x1 x2 x3 x4    y1   y2    y3    y4 new_var
#1  10 10 10  8  8.04 9.14  7.46  6.58       0
#2   8  8  8  8  6.95 8.14  6.77  5.76       0
#3  13 13 13  8  7.58 8.74 12.74  7.71       1
#4   9  9  9  8  8.81 8.77  7.11  8.84       0
#5  11 11 11  8  8.33 9.26  7.81  8.47       1
#6  14 14 14  8  9.96 8.10  8.84  7.04       1
#7   6  6  6  8  7.24 6.13  6.08  5.25       0
#8   4  4  4 19  4.26 3.10  5.39 12.50       1
#9  12 12 12  8 10.84 9.13  8.15  5.56       2
#10  7  7  7  8  4.82 7.26  6.42  7.91       0
#11  5  5  5  8  5.68 4.74  5.73  6.89       0
```

---

**2) pivot_longer:** Another option is `pivot_longer` from `tidyr` which can take multiple sets of columns and reshape it to 'long' format

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr) #1.0.0
library(tibble)
anscombe  %>% 
   rownames_to_column('rn') %>% 
   pivot_longer( -rn, names_to = c(".value", "repl"), 
        values_to = c('x', 'y'), names_pattern = '(\\D+)(\\d+)') %>% 
   group_by(rn) %>% 
   summarise(new_var =  sum(x > 10 & y > 9, na.rm = TRUE)) %>%
   arrange(as.integer(rn)) %>%
   select(-rn) %>%
   bind_cols(anscombe, .)
#   x1 x2 x3 x4    y1   y2    y3    y4 new_var
#1  10 10 10  8  8.04 9.14  7.46  6.58       0
#2   8  8  8  8  6.95 8.14  6.77  5.76       0
#3  13 13 13  8  7.58 8.74 12.74  7.71       1
#4   9  9  9  8  8.81 8.77  7.11  8.84       0
#5  11 11 11  8  8.33 9.26  7.81  8.47       1
#6  14 14 14  8  9.96 8.10  8.84  7.04       1
#7   6  6  6  8  7.24 6.13  6.08  5.25       0
#8   4  4  4 19  4.26 3.10  5.39 12.50       1
#9  12 12 12  8 10.84 9.13  8.15  5.56       2
#10  7  7  7  8  4.82 7.26  6.42  7.91       0
#11  5  5  5  8  5.68 4.74  5.73  6.89       0
```

---

**3) base R:** (similar to the logic used for the first method).  This would make it automatic as we can `split` the data into chunks based on the prefix similarity

```
anscombe$new_var <- rowSums(Reduce(`&`, Map(`>`, 
  split.default(anscombe, sub("\\d+$", "", names(anscombe))), c(10, 9))))
```

**4) unique substring prefix:** Or another option which is making use of prefix matching is loop through the unique substring prefix (would be slower than `split`) and then apply

```
rowSums(Reduce(`&`, Map(`>`, lapply(unique(sub("\\d+$", "", 
        names(anscombe))), function(nm)
           anscombe[grep(nm, names(anscombe))]), c(10, 9))))
 #[1] 0 0 1 0 1 1 0 1 2 0 0
```

Comment: Thank you for your detailed answer. I have a question on the first option. Imagine that I have 5 more columns in `anscombe`, named `z1 z2 z3 z4 w`, and that the condition I want to check is `x1>z1 & x2>z2 & x3>z3 & x4>z4 & y1 < w & y2 < w & y3 < w & y4 < w` instead of `x>10 & y>9` for each index. How should I change the line `map2(.,  c(10, 9),  `>`)`

Comment: Previous comment would apply to third and fourth options too. Second option is similar to my reshaping way to do it, but avoiding `pivot_wider` at the end. It is nice to see this way. Thank you

Comment: @iago That is a completely different question

Answer (score 2):

You could try `pmap` in `purrr` to iterate a data frame row-wisely

```r
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)
library(stringr)


new_var <- pmap_dbl(anscombe, function(...){
    row <- unlist(list(...))
    x <- row[str_subset(names(row),"^x")]
    y <- row[str_subset(names(row),"^y")]
    sum((x > 10) & (y > 9))
})


anscombe[,"new_var"] <- new_var
```

```r
> anscombe
   x1 x2 x3 x4    y1   y2    y3    y4 new_var
1  10 10 10  8  8.04 9.14  7.46  6.58       0
2   8  8  8  8  6.95 8.14  6.77  5.76       0
3  13 13 13  8  7.58 8.74 12.74  7.71       1
4   9  9  9  8  8.81 8.77  7.11  8.84       0
5  11 11 11  8  8.33 9.26  7.81  8.47       1
6  14 14 14  8  9.96 8.10  8.84  7.04       1
7   6  6  6  8  7.24 6.13  6.08  5.25       0
8   4  4  4 19  4.26 3.10  5.39 12.50       1
9  12 12 12  8 10.84 9.13  8.15  5.56       2
10  7  7  7  8  4.82 7.26  6.42  7.91       0
11  5  5  5  8  5.68 4.74  5.73  6.89       0
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I adapted to my data and the structure works, but if in the condition one of the variables (as for example the `y`s) is a `Date` -and I compare with another `Date` format variable-, I get an error `Error in charToDate(x) :  character string is not in a standard unambiguous format `

Comment: Have you tried to use `as.Date` or `lubridate::ymd` ... to convert the string to date?

Comment: I can't reproduce this error if you don't provide your data.

Answer (score 2):

Why not just

```
rowSums(anscombe[1:4] > 10 & anscombe[5:8] > 9)
# [1] 0 0 1 0 1 1 0 1 2 0 0
```

or

```
rowSums(anscombe[grep("^x", names(anscombe))] > 10 & 
          anscombe[grep("^y", names(anscombe))] > 9)
# [1] 0 0 1 0 1 1 0 1 2 0 0
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I want the new data as a new column of the data frame and in the question I ask for avoid mentioning the data frame and make code shorter as possible, but your answer helps me to keep my feet on the ground. Even so, I would have for you the same comment that first for akrun answer. If I have to compare `y1`:`y4` with another variable `w` (this just one variable) a fast adaptation of your code produces an error.

Comment: Do you mean this: `anscombe[grep("^y", names(anscombe))] == c(8.04, 8.47, 8.74, 5.56, 5.76, 8.84, 5.25, 7.91, 12.5, 4.82, 4.74)`?

Comment: It can be a problem of formats. Some of my variables have `Date` format and I get, for example, this: `Error in is.data.frame(x) : 
  (list) object cannot be coerced to type 'double'
In addition: Warning messages:
1: In is.data.frame(x) :
  Incompatible methods ("Ops.data.frame", "Ops.Date") for ">"
2: In .[grep("^fecha_ini[0-9]+$", names(.))] > fecha_or :
  longer object length is not a multiple of shorter object length`

Comment: Or also `Error in Ops.data.frame(.[grep("^fecha_ini[0-9]+$", names(.))], .["fecha_indx"]) : 
  ‘<’ only defined for equally-sized data frames`

Comment: Probably you need to ask another question, but may this help: `tmp <- as.character(seq(Sys.Date(), Sys.Date()+20, "day")); class(tmp); tmp <- as.Date(tmp); class(tmp); tmp[1:10] == tmp[c(1:5, 15:20)]; tmp[1:10] == tmp[c(1:5, 16:20)]`.